# Демонстрационная программа tensorflow выводит неизвестные символы

Tags: python, tensorflow

Извините, знакомлюсь с tensorflow, на сайте производителя, код для быстрого старта. Вывод на консоль справа. Если использовать создание сети например с помощью tf.nn.conv2d и выводить

```
train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
          x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
```

, то работает нормально. В коде используется модуль keras, получил результат неизвестные символы. TensorFlow-gpu1.5. Как это можно исправить не подскажите.
Код:

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

[image: справа фиолетовым вывод]

Comment: Это загрузка данных mnist, но почему он так загружает непонятно. Должно быть такого не должно быть.

Comment: Если вы про отображение текста то надо просто в cmd этот скрипт запустить

Comment: @Alexandr1234567890, не совсем понимаю суть вопроса. Если я запускаю код из вашего вопроса в iPython/Jupyter, то все замечательно работает. `mnist.load_data()` замечательно сначала скачивает данные, а потом возвращает их уже в разбитом на тренировочный и проверочный дата сеты...

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в интернете для тех кто тоже будет начинать с tensorFlow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import pickle
import gzip
#mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
if sys.version_info < (3,):
    data = pickle.load.load(f)
else:
    data = pickle.load(f, encoding='bytes')
f.close()
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = data
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.fit()
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Нужно скачать архив mnist.pkl.gz и выполнить этот код. Спасибо